# SQLAlchemy: How to keep the record ID and its relationship record in sync for new records (pre-commit)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When creating new records, I'd expect that foreign key fields, and their relationship object would stay in sync (if I change one the other would change to reflect), but this doesn't seem to be the case. Is this possible to do?

Given the following:

```
Base = declarative_base();

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user';
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True);
    name = Column(String);
    fullname = Column(String);
    password = Column(String);

    equipment = relationship('Equipment', backref='user');


class Equipment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'equipment';
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True);
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False);
    name = Column(String);


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True);
Base.metadata.create_all(engine);
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine);
conn = session();

conn.add_all([
    User(name='bill', fullname='Bill W.', password='rlrrlrll'),       # id=1
    User(name='tony', fullname='Tony I.', password='EADGBe'),         # id=2
    User(name='ozzy', fullname='Ozzy O.', password='durrrr'),         # id=3
    User(name='geezer', fullname='Terence B.', password='password'),  # id=4
    ]);
```

I can create related records in either of the two ways:

```
guitar = Equipment(
    user = conn.query(User).filter(User.name == 'tony').one(),
    name = 'Gibson SG');

drums = Equipment(
    user_id = 1,
    name = 'Ludwigs');
```

Following these lines I'd expect guitar.user_id to be 2, and drums.user to be the 'bill' object, but in both cases they're None. After I conn.add()/conn.commit() then it starts working a little more like I'd expect (both complementary fields return non-None values).

Is there any way for this to work pre-commit? I'd like to be able to construct new records either way (by ID or by object), and in library functions be able to reliably access the ID or object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by flushing:

```
conn.add(guitar)
conn.add(name)
conn.flush()
```

Flushing emits the `INSERT` queries but does not `COMMIT`, meaning you can `ROLLBACK` later if you need to.